# Creating a Snake using Sprites in cocos2d-x (c++)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am building Snakes and ladders and would like to create the snakes dynamically. I have three sprites the head, body and tail. I need to make sure that it is curved. I can't figure out what to use in cocos2d-x. I created a curve using cardinalspline, but I do not know how to add the sprites on that curve. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have the head, the tail and the body (but in a curved shape) I suppose that it is enough to combine the textures and generate the image, I would do it in an image editor but I see the need for some snakes to be longer than others -> http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/combining-textures-for-a-sprite/3609